# Arduino Wont Run Program at 4 Mhz

Tags: arduino-nano, atmega328

I want my Arduino Nano to consume as little power as possible, so I have been lowering the clock frequency with `CLKPR` from the default 16 MhZ speed. I successfully ran the program at 8 Mhz by setting `CLKPR=0x01`, but am unable to see any output in the serial monitor or any sign of the program running successfully at 4 Mhz (`CLKPR=0x02`). My project involves transmitting data between Arduino and an Android via Bluetooth, and I can see the receive LED blink on the Nano at 4 Mhz. However, for some reason it does not step through the code, and Serial monitor wont print statements. My Nano is a cheap knockoff so it's possible the chip is not designed to run at 4 Mhz. I've also tried the same test on a knockoff Uno and got the same results. Please let me know if you have any suggestions. I've included the code I'm trying to run:

```
int state = 0;
int stateData = 0;
int ultraPin = 10;
int trigPin = 11;    // Trigger
int echoPin = 12;    // Echo
long duration, cm;
unsigned char inches;
unsigned long timer;

void setup() {
  CLKPR = 0x80;
  CLKPR = 0x02; // 4 Mhz
  pinMode(ultraPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);  
  digitalWrite(ultraPin, LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600*4); // multiply baud rate by inverse of clock frequency factor
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available() > 0){ // Checks whether data is comming from the serial port
    stateData = Serial.read();
    if (stateData == 48){ // ON signal from phone
      Serial.write(50); // confirm signal received
      timer = millis();
      digitalWrite(ultraPin, HIGH);
      while (true){
          digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
          delayMicroseconds(2/4);
          digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
          delayMicroseconds(10/4);
          digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
          pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
          duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
          cm = (duration / 2) / 29.1;   // Divide by 29.1 or multiply by 0.0343
          inches = (duration / 2) / 74; // Divide by 74 or multiply by 0.0135
          Serial.write(inches);
          delay(50/4);           
          stateData = Serial.read();     
          if (stateData != 49){
            // receipt from android
            unsigned long timeElapse = millis() - timer;
            if (timeElapse > 5000/4) {
              break;
            } 
          }
          else {
              // reset the timer
              timer = millis();
            }
      }
    }
 }
 delay(200/4);
}
```

Comment: `delayMicroseconds(2/4);` is just as calling `delayMicroseconds(0);` Not sure if this is a valid argument for this function.

Comment: How are you programming the Nano? How do you set the correct fuses for 4MHz? Are you using an external crystal or the internal oscillator?

Comment: I am using the internal oscillator. I don't know where the fuses are and didn't think I needed to touch hardware

Comment: A Nano is normally clocked at 16 MHz off a ceramic resonator. If you want to use the internal oscillator (which runs at roughly 8 MHz), you have to use an ISP programmer to change the fuses. `CLKPR` allows you to change the prescaler at run time, but not the clock source.

Comment: Not sure if changing the prescaler modifies power consumption.

Comment: @EdgarBonet But I could change prescaler to 8 Mhz at run time. Or was it still clocked at 16 Mhz?

Comment: As I said before: at run time you can change the prescaler (e.g. to divide the frequency by 4), but not the clock source (you cannot switch from the 16 MHz ceramic resonator to 8 MHz internal RC oscillator).

Comment: ok, so i guess what you are saying is changing the prescaler doesnt do anything without changing the clock source.

Comment: I think what I am looking for is sleep mode with some interrupt when serial message is received. Thanks for the help, my problem is resolved: https://www.megunolink.com/articles/wake-on-serial-message/#:~:text=Almost%20every%20digital%20pin%20on,interrupt%20to%20wake%20the%20device.